# Convert String to "yyy-MM-dd" format with Date as data type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql, crud

I'm trying to get the data stored in database by getting the date then populate the table.

```
    List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Record> records

try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<World> query = null;

        query = session.createQuery("from World where date like :dateCont, World.class);
        query.setParameter("dateCont", "%" + contents.get(0) + "%");

        worlds = query.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem here is that it gives me an error exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   class java.util.Date (java.lang.String and java.util.Date are in
>   module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

I know what's wrong because the `List<String> contents` values are string and needed to be converted to Date but I tried so many codes and it doesn't work.

```
//The following are the codes that I tried but it won't work:

//FIRST

 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(contentsStart.get(0));
 new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);

//---------------------------------------

//SECOND

Date newDate;
DateFormat formatter = null;

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
newDate = (Date) formatter.parse(contentsStart.get(0));
```

So, is there any way to change the given value to date but it should retains the format "yyyy-MM-dd" and the datatype should be Date.

> PS: the format of date in database is "yyyy-MM-dd" also. 
>   Both my date entity field and date from DB is both Date as their
>   datatype.

Comment: a date doesn't have a "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

Comment: @Stultuske yes but to get the data from the database, format should be the same, right? The format of my dates in database is "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: no, the type has to be the same. If it's a varchar in your db, read it as a String, if it's a Date in your DB, read it as a Date.

Comment: Dates in java have a defualt format if you display them. You can only change the output format with `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date)`

Comment: @Stultuske Date is the type in my DB. Values stored in "contents" are from .txt file, so I parse it first to Date and format it in "yyyy-MM-dd" using the following codes: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(value);
 contents.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));`

But that datatype stored in contents are string because of ".format(value)". That's why I'm asking how to make the values in contents Date as datatype again.

Comment: @LenitaQuejado you don't need to format your date before persisting it. It just needs to be the right type. Applying a format to it does not alter the time(stamp) set

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes that is working but '.format(date)' is a string and that's my problem. It needs to be in datatype Data

Comment: @Stultuske may I know how? Sample codes or more detail explanations?

Comment: @Stultuske and I forgot, values in .txt file written as "MM/dd/yyyy" so I need to changed the format into "yyyy-MM-dd" that's why I used `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date)` <- and this change the data type back to string.

Comment: no, you don't need to change the format. you just need to read it into an object of type Date. again: an object of type Date doesn't have a format, nor does it have to.

Comment: `World.date` is a `java.util.Date`, but you want to match it using `LIKE` with wildcards around it? I think you're doing just about every part of this wrong. Replace the `like` with `=` and use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `java.util.Date`, so that you don't need the `Temporal` annotation, and then just pass a `LocalDate` parameter value. You're trying to jump 5 unnecessary hoops and looking to add even more as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like` operator only on string (`VARCHAR`) fields. In the WHERE clause you have to convert your field to string (using format function) in order to be able to use `LIKE`. So you have to call the convert function (also) IN THE QUERY.

Unfortunately, there are no DATE-functions in EJBQL, so you will have to switch to the native query. For example, for Oracle you can use `TO_CHAR` like this

```
SELECT ... WHERE TO_CHAR(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') LIKE ...
```

For good performance you will have to add a functional index.

See also http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_char_datetime

---

One alternative would be to add a new string column `date_string`, that will contain the formatted representation of your date and use this column with `LIKE`. But you will have to make absolutely sure, that both dates are always synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date d1= (Date) format.parse(yourDate);
```